# Editing HTML tags color in VSCode

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, themes, syntax-highlighting

Here's how my settings.json file looks like:

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {

        "textMateRules": [
            {
                "scope": "entity.name.tag",
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#7ea4df"
                }
            }
        ]
    },

{
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Visual Studio Light",
    "window.zoomLevel": 0,
    "editor.minimap.enabled": false,
    "breadcrumbs.enabled": true
}
```

The problem is that when I save this file, my theme changes to dark "black" color. How can I preserve my theme and still edit the HTML tags colors?